# Weird <!--php tags form database

Tags: php, database, wordpress, formatting

Has anyone had this issue when i pull data out from the database it looks like below, it looks fine in the actually database table.

I am using wordpress. Any suggestion scratching my head.

these are the tags

```
<pre><!--? if (function_exists('externalGetSociofluidButtonsForCurrentUrl'))
                {echo externalGetSociofluidButtonsForCurrentUrl();} ?-->
<!--?php DisplayVotes(get_the_ID()); ?-->
<!--?php MostVotedAllTime(); ?--></pre>
```

Comment: Is that unserialised data from the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a bad way of commenting out some PHP code, except since it's an HTML quote, the raw code will be sent to the client. In functional terms:

```
<pre><?php /* echo "this will not be executed" */ ?></pre>
```

and

```
<pre><!--?php echo "this will not be executed" ?--></pre>
```

both disable the echo call, but the HTML quote version will send the commented-out code to the browser, whereas using `/* */` will just send `<pre></pre>`.